# Can't get mysql_insert_id() to work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-insert-id

I tried this:

```
$cid = mysql_insert_id($this->result);
$this->result = "<div class='alert alert-success'>" . sprintf(_('Successfully added user id <b>%s</b> to the database.'), $cid) . "</div>";
```

but I only get this error:

Warning: mysql_insert_id(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in

This is the entire function (i added this **$cid = mysql_insert_id($this->result);** hoping to retrieve the id of the inserted data):

```
private function adduser() {

    if (!empty($this->error)) return false;

    $params = array(
        ':user_level' => parent::getOption('default-level'),
        ':name'       => $this->name,
        ':email'      => $this->email,
        ':username'   => $this->username,
        ':password'   => parent::hashPassword($this->password)
    );

    parent::query("INSERT INTO `login_users` (`user_level`, `name`, `email`, `username`, `password`)
                    VALUES (:user_level, :name, :email, :username, :password);", $params);

    $shortcodes = array(
        'site_address'  =>  SITE_PATH,
        'full_name'     =>  $this->name,
        'username'      =>  $this->username,
        'email'         =>  $this->email,
        'password'      =>  $this->password
    );

    $subj = parent::getOption('email-add-user-subj');
    $msg = parent::getOption('email-add-user-msg');

    if(!parent::sendEmail($this->email, $subj, $msg, $shortcodes))
        $this->error = _('ERROR. Mail not sent');
    $cid = mysql_insert_id($this->result);
    $this->result = "<div class='alert alert-success'>" . sprintf(_('Successfully added user <b>%s</b> to the database. Credentials sent to user.'), $cid) . "</div>";

}
```

This is the connection to the database:

```
<?php
$host = "xxx"; 
$dbName = "xxx"; 
$dbUser = "xxx"; 
$dbPass = "xxx"; 
?>
```

Comment: We would need to see a few preceeding lines - especially as at the end you set $this->result to text

Comment: Where's your query and designated result? Please updat with some more lines of code. 
First off, using `this->result` as the result identifier and then using it to set a string doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_insert_id()` takes a resource link, i.e. database handle, as an argument not the query result. What does `$this->result` contain?

Answer (score 1):

Check [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Parameter for `mysql_insert_id` is Link_Identifier. But I guess you are passing result. Try

```
$cid = mysql_insert_id();
```

or your $this->result must be connection identifier returned by mysql_connect().

Comment: Resulted in: Warning: mysql_insert_id() [function.mysql-insert-id]: A link to the server could not be established in

Answer (score 0):

You are already using PDO, switch to:

```
$cid = self::$dbh->lastInsertId(); // PDO for mysql_insert_id
```

Comment: I got this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Generic::lastInsertId() in

Comment: It means your parent hasn't that function. Aren't you using PDO?

Comment: Yes, so how do I add this function to my parent?

Comment: I don't know how your parent it's constructed .. Please post your parent's `query` function