# How do I add lastInsertId()?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, lastinsertid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't get mysql_insert_id() to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490165/cant-get-mysql-insert-id-to-work)

I want to print the last inserted id using **lastInsertId()** on this function:

```
private function adduser() {

    if (!empty($this->error)) return false;

    $params = array(
        ':user_level' => parent::getOption('default-level'),
        ':name'       => $this->name,
        ':email'      => $this->email,
        ':username'   => $this->username,
        ':password'   => parent::hashPassword($this->password)
    );

    parent::query("INSERT INTO `login_users` (`user_level`, `name`, `email`, `username`, `password`)
                    VALUES (:user_level, :name, :email, :username, :password);", $params);

    $shortcodes = array(
        'site_address'  =>  SITE_PATH,
        'full_name'     =>  $this->name,
        'username'      =>  $this->username,
        'email'         =>  $this->email,
        'password'      =>  $this->password
    );

    $subj = parent::getOption('email-add-user-subj');
    $msg = parent::getOption('email-add-user-msg');
    $cid = parent::lastInsertId();

    if(!parent::sendEmail($this->email, $subj, $msg, $shortcodes))
        $this->error = _('ERROR. Mail not sent');

    $this->result = "<div class='alert alert-success'>" . sprintf(_('Successfully added user <b>%s</b> to the database. Credentials sent to user.'), $cid) . "</div>";

}
```

I have added this:

```
$cid = parent::lastInsertId();
```

and then added **$cid** here:

```
$this->result = "<div class='alert alert-success'>" . sprintf(_('Successfully added user <b>%s</b> to the database. Credentials sent to user.'), $cid) . "</div>";
```

But I keep getting:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Generic::lastInsertId() in
```

The database connection looks like this:

```
public function dbConn() {

    include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php');

    try {
        self::$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbName}", $dbUser, $dbPass);
        self::$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return '<div class="alert alert-error">'._('Database error: '). $e->getMessage() . '</div>';
    }


}
```

Any ideas how I should properly add **lastInsertId()** ?

Comment: what framework/class you are using for DB?

Comment: raina77ow, yes since I discovered that this has nothing to do with mysql_insert_id() since this is PDO.

Comment: raina77ow, sorry this is not Magento, this is a user login script which im trying to modify by adding lastInsertId(), but I can't get it to work.

Comment: What you basically need is to call lastInsertId() method on your connection object. From the snippets shown it looks like it's stored in `self::$dbh`, so probably it should be used like this: `self::$dbh->lastInsertId()`

Comment: raina77ow, thanks a million, it worked, wow. You are my hero, thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
$cid = parent::lastInsertId();
```

with

```
self::$dbh->lastInsertId();
```

... as (it looks like) your connection object is stored in the `dbh` field of this anonymous class we're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

LastInsertID is a method of PDO class.

You are calling it on the `Generic` class, that has no method `LastInsertID();`

Comment: So how do I call it the right way?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: I tried $cid = PDO::lastInsertId(); and got this error instead: Fatal error: Non-static method PDO::lastInsertId() cannot be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in

Comment: It is not clear if you have a PDO object available in your code?